# bxSlider position issue

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I'm developing this website http://martindue.dk/esoft/ and sometimes when resizing the window, the slider gets all messy and the position is off.

An example of this error can be viewed right here:

[bxSlider error http://martindue.dk/esoft/bxerror.PNG](http://martindue.dk/esoft/bxerror.PNG)

I'm altering the design of the bxSlider a bit, the CSS are the following:

```
    .position-frontpage-about-slider {
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;

        ul.frontpage-slider {
            text-align: center;

            li {
                font-weight: 300;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 0 40px;

                strong {
                    font-weight: 600;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea on what causing this position offset?

Comment: can you paste how you are calling bxslider.

Comment: `$fpSlider.bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        infiniteLoop: false
    });`